# Не видит внешний ключ(нет чекбокса для выбора элементов из связанной таблицы).QSqlRelationalTableModel и setItemDelegate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, sqlite3

Вот этим кодом пытаюсь сделать то, что изображено на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    self.view = QTableView()
    self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    self.view.setModel(self.model)
    self.view.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.view))
```

В итоге получается обычная таблица без поддержки внешнего ключа, не понимаю, в чём проблема. Использую `sqlite`.

Вот полный код:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QTableView, QWidget, QGridLayout, 
    QPushButton, QComboBox, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, 
    QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, 
    QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlRelationalDelegate)
import sqlite3 
import traceback
import os

class View(QWidget):# Класс окна для отображения таблиц
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.dbname = ''
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1)
        self.btnAdd = QPushButton('Добавить запись')
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.add_record)
        self.btnDel = QPushButton('Удалить запись')
        self.btnDel.clicked.connect(self.del_record)
        self.btnOpen = QPushButton('Открыть базу данных')
        self.btnClean = QPushButton('Clean')#
        #self.btnClean.clicked.connect(self.clean)#
        self.btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.open_db)
        self.box = QComboBox()
        self.box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_index)
        self.edt = QLineEdit()
        self.Islovie = QLineEdit()#
        self.Uslovie = QLabel()#
        self.lab = QLabel()
        self.lab.setText("Условие")
        self.edt.textChanged.connect(self.search)# 1 left edit
        self.Uslovie.setText("Поиск по столбцу\n Столбцы с нуля")
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        grid.addWidget(self.view,0,0,4,4)
        grid.addWidget(self.box,4,0,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btnOpen,4,1,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btnAdd,4,2,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btnDel,4,3,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btnClean,6,3,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.edt,5,1,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.lab,5,0,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.Uslovie,5,2,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.Islovie,5,3,1,1)
        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.view))   

    def search(self):
        try:
            print("change")
            self.proxymodel.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(""+self.edt.text()+""))
            self.proxymodel.setFilterKeyColumn(int(self.Islovie.text()))
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())

    def open_db(self):
        dbname,_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Открыть базу данных',self.dbname,'*.db *.sqlite')
        if not dbname: return
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.db.setDatabaseName(self.dbname)
        if not(self.db.open()):
            QMessageBox.critical(self,"",self.db.lastError().text())
            return
        self.box.clear()
        self.box.addItems(self.db.tables())
    
    def on_index(self):
        table = self.box.currentText()
        self.model.setTable(table)
        if table == 'tbl':
            self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Вопрос")
            self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Ответ")
        self.model.select()
        
    def add_record(self):    #work!!!!
        idx = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(idx)
        
    def del_record(self):    #work!!!!
        idx = self.view.currentIndex()
        self.model.removeRow(idx.row())


if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = View()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для того чтобы дать вам какие-нибудь советы опубликуйте пример, который демонстрирует вашу проблему!  И скажите пожалуйста ваш предыдущий вопрос еще не имеет правильного ответа?

Comment: @S.Nick , Дополнил тему, как вы и просили

Comment: @S.Nick, Спасибо, на ту запись нашёл ответ

Comment: Уточните, что в предоставленном примере работает не так как вам хочется?

Comment: @S.Nick, на первом скриншоте вы видите чекбокс у поля со связью, то есть,  можно выбрать существующую запись из дочерней таблицы. На втором скриншоте при нажатии на поле, на котором находится связь, просто даётся возможность редактировать, но не появляется чекбокса с выбором

Answer (score 0):

Вы опубликовали не полный пример, он не демонстрирует проблему.
Нет примера создания таблиц и их связи.

Пример приведенный мною поможет вам получить желаемый результат.
Обратите внимание как связаны таблицы и организован `ComboBox`.
Проанализируйте созданную БД `phonelog-fk.db`. Пробуйте:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import (QDate, QDateTime, QFile, QVariant, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDataWidgetMapper,QComboBox,
                             QDateTimeEdit, QDialog, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QPixmap,QCursor
from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlRelation,
                         QSqlRelationalDelegate, QSqlRelationalTableModel)

#import qrc_resources  файла ресурсов нету

MAC = True
try:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import qt_mac_set_native_menubar
except ImportError:
    MAC = False

ID, CALLER, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, TOPIC, OUTCOMEID = range(6)
DATETIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"


def createFakeData():
    import random

    print("Dropping tables...")
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE calls")
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE outcomes")
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Creating tables...")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE outcomes (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)""")

    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE calls (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        caller VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        starttime DATETIME NOT NULL,
        endtime DATETIME NOT NULL,
        topic VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        outcomeid INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (outcomeid) REFERENCES outcomes)""")                   # <-------
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Заполнение outcomes...")
    for name in ("Resolved", "Unresolved", "Calling back", "Escalate", "Wrong number"):
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO outcomes (name) VALUES ('{0}')".format(name))

    topics = ("Complaint", "Information request", "Off topic",
              "Information supplied", "Complaint", "Complaint")
    now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO calls (caller, starttime, endtime, "
                  "topic, outcomeid) VALUES (:caller, :starttime, "
                  ":endtime, :topic, :outcomeid)")

    for name in ('Joshan Cockerall', 'Ammanie Ingham',
               'Diarmuid Bettington', 'Juliana Bannister',
               'Oakley-Jay Buxton', 'Reilley Collinge',
               'Ellis-James Mcgehee', 'Jazmin Lawton',
               'Lily-Grace Smythe', 'Coskun Lant', 'Lauran Lanham',
               'Millar Poindexter', 'Naqeeb Neild', 'Maxlee Stoddart',
               'Rebia Luscombe', 'Briana Christine', 'Charli Pease',
               'Deena Mais', 'Havia Huffman', 'Ethan Davie',
               'Thomas-Jack Silver', 'Harpret Bray', 'Leigh-Ann Goodliff',
               'Seoras Bayes', 'Jenna Underhill', 'Veena Helps',
               'Mahad Mcintosh', 'Allie Hazlehurst', 'Aoife Warrington',
               'Cameron Burton', 'Yildirim Ahlberg', 'Alissa Clayton',
               'Josephine Weber', 'Fiore Govan', 'Howard Ragsdale',
               'Tiernan Larkins', 'Seren Sweeny', 'Arisha Keys',
               'Kiki Wearing', 'Kyran Ponsonby', 'Diannon Pepper',
               'Mari Foston', 'Sunil Manson', 'Donald Wykes',
               'Rosie Higham', 'Karmin Raines', 'Tayyibah Leathem',
               'Kara-jay Knoll', 'Shail Dalgleish', 'Jaimie Sells'):
        start = now.addDays(-random.randint(1, 30))
        start = now.addSecs(-random.randint(60 * 5, 60 * 60 * 2))
        end = start.addSecs(random.randint(20, 60 * 13))
        start=start.toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        end=end.toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)  
        topic = random.choice(topics)
        outcomeid = int(random.randint(1, 5))
        query.bindValue(":caller", name)
        query.bindValue(":starttime", start)
        query.bindValue(":endtime", end)
        query.bindValue(":topic", topic)
        query.bindValue(":outcomeid", outcomeid)
        query.exec_()
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Calls:")
    query.exec_("SELECT calls.id, calls.caller, calls.starttime, "
            "calls.endtime, calls.topic, calls.outcomeid, "
            "outcomes.name FROM calls, outcomes "
            "WHERE calls.outcomeid = outcomes.id "
            "ORDER by calls.starttime")

    while query.next():
        id        = query.value(ID)
        caller    = str(query.value(CALLER))
        starttime = str(query.value(STARTTIME))
        endtime   = str(query.value(ENDTIME))
        topic     = str(query.value(TOPIC))
        outcome   = str(query.value(6))
    QApplication.processEvents()


class PhoneLogDlg(QDialog):

    FIRST, PREV, NEXT, LAST = range(4)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhoneLogDlg, self).__init__(parent)

        callerLabel     = QLabel("&Caller:")
        self.callerEdit = QLineEdit()
        callerLabel.setBuddy(self.callerEdit)
        today = QDate.currentDate()
        startLabel = QLabel("&Start:")
        self.startDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
        startLabel.setBuddy(self.startDateTime)
        self.startDateTime.setDateRange(today, today)
        self.startDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        endLabel = QLabel("&End:")
        self.endDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
        endLabel.setBuddy(self.endDateTime)
        self.endDateTime.setDateRange(today, today)
        self.endDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        topicLabel = QLabel("&Topic:")
        topicEdit = QLineEdit()
        topicLabel.setBuddy(topicEdit)

        outcomeLabel = QLabel("&Outcome:")
        self.outcomeComboBox = QComboBox()                            # <------
        outcomeLabel.setBuddy(self.outcomeComboBox)

        firstButton = QPushButton()
        firstButton.setIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/first.jpg"))
        prevButton = QPushButton()
        prevButton.setIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/previous.svg"))
        nextButton = QPushButton()
        nextButton.setIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/next.svg"))
        lastButton = QPushButton()
        lastButton.setIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/last.png"))
        addButton = QPushButton("&Add")
        addButton.setIcon(QIcon(":/add.png"))
        deleteButton = QPushButton("&Delete")
        deleteButton.setIcon(QIcon(":/delete.png"))
        quitButton = QPushButton("&Quit")
        quitButton.setIcon(QIcon(":/quit.png"))
        if not MAC:
            addButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
            deleteButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        fieldLayout = QGridLayout()
        fieldLayout.addWidget(callerLabel, 0, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.callerEdit, 0, 1, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(startLabel, 1, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.startDateTime, 1, 1)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(endLabel, 1, 2)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.endDateTime, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(topicLabel, 2, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(topicEdit, 2, 1, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(outcomeLabel, 3, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.outcomeComboBox, 3, 1, 1, 3)             # <------
        navigationLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        navigationLayout.addWidget(firstButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(prevButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(nextButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(lastButton)
        fieldLayout.addLayout(navigationLayout, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(addButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(deleteButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(quitButton)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(fieldLayout)
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("calls")
        self.model.setRelation(OUTCOMEID, QSqlRelation("outcomes", "id", "name"))
        self.model.setSort(STARTTIME, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model.select()

        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.callerEdit, CALLER)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.startDateTime, STARTTIME)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.endDateTime, ENDTIME)
        self.mapper.addMapping(topicEdit, TOPIC)
        relationModel = self.model.relationModel(OUTCOMEID)
        self.outcomeComboBox.setModel(relationModel)                           # <------
        self.outcomeComboBox.setModelColumn(relationModel.fieldIndex("name"))  # <------
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.outcomeComboBox, OUTCOMEID)                # <------
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        firstButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.FIRST))
        prevButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.PREV))
        nextButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.NEXT))
        lastButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.LAST))  
        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord)  
        quitButton.clicked.connect(self.done)
        self.setWindowTitle("Phone Log")


    def done(self, result=None):
        self.mapper.submit()
        QDialog.done(self, True)

    def addRecord(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.mapper.submit()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
        now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.startDateTime.setDateTime(now)
        self.endDateTime.setDateTime(now)
        self.outcomeComboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.outcomeComboBox.findText("Unresolved")) # <------
        self.callerEdit.setFocus()                                                        # <------


    def deleteRecord(self):
        caller = self.callerEdit.text()
        starttime = self.startDateTime.dateTime().toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        if (QMessageBox.question(self,
                "Delete",
                "Delete call made by<br>{0} on {1}?".format(caller,starttime),
                QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No) ==
                QMessageBox.No):
            return

        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.model.removeRow(row)
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.model.select()
        if row + 1 >= self.model.rowCount():
            row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)


    def saveRecord(self, where):
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.mapper.submit()
        if where == PhoneLogDlg.FIRST:
            row = 0
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.PREV:
            row = 0 if row <= 1 else row - 1
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.NEXT:
            row += 1
            if row >= self.model.rowCount():
                row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.LAST:
            row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "phonelog-fk.db")
    create = not QFile.exists(filename)

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(filename)

    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Phone Log",
            QString("Database Error: %1").arg(db.lastError().text()))
        sys.exit(1)

    splash = None
    if create:
        app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))
        splash = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap("im.png")
        splash.setPixmap(pixmap)
        splash.setMask(pixmap.createHeuristicMask())
        splash.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
        rect = app.desktop().availableGeometry()
        splash.move((rect.width() - pixmap.width()) / 2,
                    (rect.height() - pixmap.height()) / 2)
        splash.show()
        app.processEvents()
        createFakeData()

    form = PhoneLogDlg()
    form.show()
    if create:
        splash.close()
        app.processEvents()
        app.restoreOverrideCursor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Буду изучать